# Run C/C++ code in terminal instead of debug console in VS Code on macOS?

Tags: c++, c, macos, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up VS Code as a C/C++ development environment using gcc/g++ installed from homebrew on my MacBook.

It all works fine. When I run a file, it finds `gcc` which I installed with `homebrew`. However, the output is shown in the debug console instead of in the terminal which I would prefer:
[image]

I tried to look online, but I couldn't find any way to do it. In addition, on my Windows desktop, I followed the same procedure to set up VS Code and it did run in the integrated terminal.

Why does it run in the terminal on Windows by default and not on Mac, and how can I configure it to run in a terminal?

Answer (score 2):

File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Run Code Config -> Run In Terminal

This should work ^^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set the debug console as the default option. You can type "ctrl+shift+P" and then choose launch.json. Delete the line "console": "internalConsole"

Answer (score 0):

#### For the Microsoft C/C++ extension

> Why does it run in the terminal on Windows by default and not on Mac and how can I configure it to run in a terminal?

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_externalconsole specifically the section for macOS. At least for debugging with a launch configuration, it says:

> Due to limitations within lldb-mi, integratedTerminal support is not available.

And compare

> When set to true, it will spawn an external console through lldb-mi. When set to false, the output can be seen in VS Code's debugConsole.

with what it says for Windows and Linux, where when it is set to `false` on those platforms, it defaults to the integrated terminal.

#### For the CodeLLDB extension

This should already be the default (in `"lldb"` launch configs, `"terminal": "integrated"` [is the default](https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/blob/master/MANUAL.md#launching-a-new-process)).

Answer (score -1):

You could run it from the terminal.
You can open a terminal via `ctrl`+<kbd>`</kbd>.
This works great for me.