# Output in VsCode displayed in debug console rather than the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner who just started learning how to code, but was having trouble setting up my VS code for C++. I wrote a simple Hello World program, but my output is appearing in the debug console rather than appearing in the terminal.

I have installed the extensions Intellisense and configured in the settings so CodeRunners runs in the terminal, but my output appears in the debug console. In the terminal window while my program is running, it only displays,

"Executing task: C/C++: clang++ build active file
Starting build...
Build finished successfully.

- Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: Since no one here can your screen, you should try your best to post the exact settings for others to know what you configured. You can use screenshots or video clips if you find it hard to describe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run C/C++ code in terminal instead of debug console in VS Code on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234849/run-c-c-code-in-terminal-instead-of-debug-console-in-vs-code-on-macos)

Answer (score 0):

- Open the `.vscode` directory in your project and look for the `launch.json` file. Make sure that the "console" property is set to "integratedTerminal". Here's an example configuration:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C++ Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<your_program_name>",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "externalConsole": false
    }
]
```

- Open the VS Code settings (File > Preferences > Settings) and search for "Code Runner". Find the "Code-runner: Run in Terminal" setting and ensure that it is enabled.
- Make sure you're running the appropriate task to build and run your C++ program. In VS Code, press `Ctrl+Shift+B` (Windows/Linux) or `Cmd+Shift+B` (Mac) to open the task selection menu. Select the task for building and running C++ code (e.g., "C/C++: clang++ build active file"). This should compile and execute your program in the terminal.
- If you've made changes to the settings or configurations, try restarting VS Code to ensure the changes take effect.

Comment: This does not work in "remote attach" mode.

Answer (score -1):

After installing the "code runner" extention and enabling the "run in terminal" setting, there will be three options in the play button in the upper right corner: "Debug C/C++ file", "Run code" and "Run C/C++ file".  The "Run code" would execute the code and output directly in the terminal and the play button would be set default to use the "Run code" after you use it once.