# A question about vscode launching a terminal for c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Question: I'm writing c++ in vscode on macOS, is there any extension to make vscode launch Kitty.app instead of terminal.app for c++ program debugging?

I mainly want vscode to exit the terminal app directly after running a program like it does in windows and Linux but macOS doesn't exit completely after closing the window.

Comment: I would assume it would be something in the `launch.json` file. What does [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs) say?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76597837/output-in-vscode-displayed-in-debug-console-rather-than-the-terminal

Comment: is it not just by setting `"externalConsole": true,` and then configuring `terminal.integrated.automationProfile.osx`?

Comment: If I set externalConsole": true , when clicking debug, vscode will open terminal.app as a console, I want to use Kitty.app instead of terminal, can I do it by configuring terminal.integrated. automationProfile.osx?